# How to replace sublists within a list?

Tags: python

I have a list. this list has sublists. Each sublist contains a string. I want to apply `.replace()` to these strings to change a letter.

```
mylist = [["aus"],["ausser"],["bei"],["mit"],["noch"],["seit"],["von"],["zu"]]

for sublist in mylist:
    sublist = [stuff.replace("s", "Q") for stuff in sublist]
print(mylist)
```

But it just returns the original list. It should return

`[["auQ"],["auQQer"],["bei"],["mit"],["noch"],["Qeit"],["von"],["zu"]]`

## Question

Why doesn't my code change my subslists even though I redefine them within the for loop?

Comment: it prints your original list..because you're *printing it*, start by changing `print(mylist)` to something else

Comment: what you modified is just a copy of sublist and reassigned to a new sublist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Hamms 's comment:

> the reason the original doesn't work is because when it assigns the
>   new list to sublist, it's merely overwriting the reference to the sublist
>   provided by thefor loop, not the sublist itself.

This method works because it's creating an entirely new list rather than trying to modify the original:

```
mylist = [["aus"],["ausser"],["bei"],["mit"],["noch"],["seit"],["von"],["zu"]]
final = [j.replace("s", "Q") for k in mylist for j in k] 
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['auQ', 'auQQer', 'bei', 'mit', 'noch', 'Qeit', 'von', 'zu']
```

Or you can do this in order to have your desired output:

```
mylist = [["aus"],["ausser"],["bei"],["mit"],["noch"],["seit"],["von"],["zu"]]
final = [[j.replace("s", "Q")] for k in mylist for j in k] 
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['auQ'], ['auQQer'], ['bei'], ['mit'], ['noch'], ['Qeit'], ['von'], ['zu']]
```

Comment: that's clever. i wouldn't have thought of that

Comment: some explanation is warranted; the reason the original doesn't work is because when it assigns the new list to `sublist`, it's merely overwriting the _reference_ to the sublist provided by the`for` loop, not the sublist itself. This method works because it's creating an entirely new list rather than trying to modify the original

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Hamms. I'll add it to my answer, if you accept it.

Comment: @nexus66 please do

Comment: Done. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @nexus66 Quick request: So for the project i'm working on, it would be useful to not only be able to replace letters, but within each sublist add an element that is an index essentially. So for instance `[['1','auQ'], ['2','auQQer'], ['3','bei'], ['4','mit'], ['5','noch'], ['6','Qeit'], ['7','von'], ['8','zu']]` Do you know how to create such a thing? I tried but I am not really sure how to do it using a for loop with a counter in this situation....

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this in a one liner:

```
[[s.replace("s", "Q")] for l in mylist for s in l]
[['auQ'], ['auQQer'], ['bei'], ['mit'], ['noch'], ['Qeit'], ['von'], ['zu']]
```

But the reason this is happening is because you're repeatedly creating a new variable `sublist` instead of assigning to the existing sublist.  If you want to use your method, try this:

```
for l in mylist:
    l[0] = l[0].replace("s", "Q")

print(mylist)
[['auQ'], ['auQQer'], ['bei'], ['mit'], ['noch'], ['Qeit'], ['von'], ['zu']]
```

Here, the sublists are modified in place (instead of creating a new, modified sublist) which in turn modifies the original list.

Comment: I edited it out for clarity, but the `In` formatting is from `ipython` @MateenUlhaq.  So similar to a notebook!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that uses `map`:

```
mylist = [["aus"],["ausser"],["bei"],["mit"],["noch"],["seit"],["von"],["zu"]]

secondList = list(map(lambda l: [l[0].replace('s', 'Q')], mylist)) # python 3
#secondList = map(lambda l: [l[0].replace('s', 'Q')], mylist) # python 2

>>> mylist
[['aus'], ['ausser'], ['bei'], ['mit'], ['noch'], ['seit'], ['von'], ['zu']]
>>> secondList
[['auQ'], ['auQQer'], ['bei'], ['mit'], ['noch'], ['Qeit'], ['von'], ['zu']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use

```
    mylist = [["aus"],["ausser"],["bei"],["mit"],["noch"],["seit"],["von"],["zu"]]

    for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = [stuff.replace("s", "Q") for stuff in mylist[i]]
    print(mylist)
```